# PHP / Laravel Foreach Loop - Show only Items that belongs to same headline

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have a problem to view some data in the way I want to have it.

Here is a example of the array:

```
$items =         
       0 => [
               'name' => 'foo'
               'description' => 'bar'
               'url' => 'http://foobar.com'
               'headline' => 'Headline 1' 
            ],
       1 => [
               'name' => 'uni'
               'description' => 'corn'
               'url' => 'http://unicorn.com'
               'headline' => 'Headline 1' 
            ],

       2 => [
               'name' => 'awe'
               'description' => 'some'
               'url' => 'http://awesome.com'
               'headline' => 'Headline 2' 
            ],
```

And know I want to loop through the items array and want to show the headline at first and all items that have the same headline. If a item has another headline, I want to print out the other headline and the items that belongs to it.

Should look like that:

```
Headline 1 : <--- Items that do have this headline

name = foo
description = bar
url = http://foobar.com

name = uni
description = corn
url = http://unicorn.com

Headline 2 <----- items with a new headline

name = awe
description = some
url = http://awesome.com
```

I wansn't able to do that. Can someone help me there?

I've tried something like a for loop that checks the current headline with the next headline.

```
@for ($i = 0; $i <= count($items); $i++)
            <span>{{ $items[$i]['headline'] }}</span>
        @if($items[$i]['headline'] == $items[$i+1]['headline'])
        ..... 
        @ else .....
@endfor
```

But this haven't worked well

Thanks for your help and sorry because of my bad english!

Comment: You should do all these things at backend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use laravel collections with groupby() method

```
$collection = collect($items);

$items= $collection->groupBy('headline');

$items->toArray();
```

The array will be splited by headline

From Laravel Docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-groupby

Comment: I will try that, one seccond :)

Answer (score 1):

If your array was a collection before converting to an array, you could use [`groupBy()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-groupby) collection method:

```
$collection->groupBy('headline');
```

Comment: I will try that, I will reply soon :)

Comment: @WellNo I've just tried to use it on a collection with your structure and it works just fine.

Comment: I get a Call to a member function groupBy() on array. So it isn't a collection. Do you have a way to do that on a array?

Comment: @WellNo if you're getting this data from DB, just use Eloquent and do not convert it to an array. If not, use `collect($array)` method to create a collection from an array.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could help. i am writing this code in core PHP

```
$arr = array();
foreach($items as $item) {
  $arr[$item['headline']] = $item;
}
```

it will return you an array of something like

```
Array
(
    [Headline 1] => Array
        (
            [name] => uni
            [description] => corn
            [url] => http://unicorn.com
            [headline] => Headline 1
        )

    [Headline 2] => Array
        (
            [name] => awe
            [description] => some
            [url] => http://awesome.com
            [headline] => Headline 2
        )

)
```